# What might be causing the material applied on the right wall (no bricks displayed) to come out this way? (Beginner)

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I'm making a quick mock-up of a bathroom to help my dad decide on certain design choices and have ran into an issue while applying this brick texture around the "shower" portion of this scene. I'm trying to apply the very same material I applied to the left wall to the one on the right and have messed around with the sliders for quite a bit but can't get it to display the texture the same way it does on the left wall for the life of me.

The wall the texture isn't displaying properly on was created by linking four verts and adding a face, it is part of the same object as the wall on the left. I suspect this might be the issue, but I'm unsure as to how I would go about making that face its own object (if needed) and having the new material line up with the other face as these are supposed to be the same tile pattern.

[image]

Comment: You need to UV unwrap your model again.

Comment: I set that portion of the wall as a new object, unwrapped again and tried to apply the material and it still looks the same, sadly. (I'm just trying to apply a procedurally generated brick texture straight from blender itself, not really an image texture, still unwrapped to be safe,but  no luck.)

Comment: Well, if you already have unwrapped UV's you can always use UV as a texture coordinate, even for a procedural brick.

Comment: sometimes the unwraps are not being likned anymore and you need to use the option `u>>reset`